# Power Management in Ubuntu 16.04 not workinng

Tags: power-management, xfce, battery, xfce4-power-manager

I have already read several answers for similar problem and tried them but

I am facing problems with battery power management ever since I removed Unity and installed XFCE.

I have configured the display to turn off automatically after one minute but it doesn't happen. It works in the login screen though.

[image: Power Manager Settings]

I have also installed `tlp`and enabled power saving mode in nVidia x server settings.

[image]

I have uploaded results from [powerstat here](http://pastebin.com/Xxzpp818)

What I want is to turn off display automatically.

Comment: I had enabled 'Presentation Mode' in power settings. After disabling it everything is fine